# Usage of that in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> But we do believe that diligent readers will become better writers and *that* they will be equipped with the means to improve further on their own.

Is the word "that" a necessity in this sentence?

Comment: No, it is often not necessary to include words like "that", "which", "who", and so on, at the beginning of relative clauses.  If this is still confusing, please add more detail to explain why.  Otherwise the question should be closed.

Comment: Sorry to be 'picky' @Andrew, but "that they will be equipped with ..." is not a relative clause, but a content clause (aka a so-called _that_ clause).

Comment: @BillJ fair enough. Either way "that" is optional, although it does help with readability.